# Geometric proof for eigenvalues of rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I don't understand how to proof the eigenvalues of rotation matrix using geometric argument only. I know how to do it with determinant but what about the geometric way? What is the meaning of complex number as eigenvalues?

For example, find the eigenvalues for R geometrically:

### $$
R = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
$$

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwAhx.png)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If you're familiar with the isomorphism between the complex numbers and certain $2 \times 2$ real matrices you can show that the eigenvalues act on the argand plane in the same manner that the matrix acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Basically the polar form of the eigenvalue gives you the argument of the rotation.